# Uploading a photo via Objective-C HTTP Post

Tags: php, objective-c, http, ios5

I'm sending a picture building an HTTP POST like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSString *boundary = @"801f6dd4cd17";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data;boundary=------------------------------%@", boundary];


NSMutableDictionary *headerFieldsDict = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[ headerFieldsDict setObject:contentType forKey:@"Content-Type"];

[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headerFieldsDict];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

//---------- FIRST IMG
UIImage* imgLittle = [realImgButton imageForState:UIControlStateNormal];//thumImg.image;
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imgLittle, 1.0);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"------------------------------%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"img.jpg\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"------------------------------%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

But the server refuse to upload the image (it give a software error, it seems that the HTTP post it's not well parsed), the only information that i have about the server is that this client code in php works well:

```
$data['file'] = "@".$file;
$header[] = "Expect: ";
print_r($data);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://xxxxxx:yyy/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
$url = strip_tags($xml->dict->string[3]->asXML());
return $url;
```

Any ideas? or where am I wrong on the obj-c code? I try to analyze the HTTP post statement produced and it seems the same as the one produced by the php code.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to go with `-addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` instead of doing this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *headerFieldsDict = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[ headerFieldsDict setObject:contentType forKey:@"Content-Type"];

[request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headerFieldsDict];
```

All you really need to do is to add a single header to the request, but you're effectively wiping out any existing headers with the code above.

Comment: This is not true i sniffed the HTTP Post and the output is like this: http://pastebin.com/hdjgdXU5. I tried to have the same header with php code and the upload works...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) framework:
I one of my projects I use this to upload images on server:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:yourURL];
[request addPostValue:NSString  forKey:@"KEY"];
[request addPostValue:NSString forKey:@"KEY"];
... any post value you need

[request addData:image withFileName:[name of the file]
    andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"KEY"];
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive what the problem with your code is, but I have two ideas:

1. I think you might need another `\r\n` at the end of your `Content-Disposition`, like so:

   ```
   [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"img.jpg\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
   ```
2. Using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and setting your content type to `application/octet-stream` might be the issue. `[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:]` might be more appropriate for `application/octet-stream` and `image/jpeg` might be more appropriate for `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. This is just a guess though.

If you are really stumped, you could use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) (which is more up to date and lighter weight than ASIHTTPRequest). Or you could at least check out their code to see how they handle file uploads.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted looked familiar, so I checked an old app where I'd been POSTing images, and we obviously got the code from the same source (which I don't recall). Mine is almost identical, save for the boundary strings, and the fact that I took out the redundant `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY"; 

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];

[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:myImageData];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

This code works fine for me, so assuming nothing is wrong with your image data, your boundary may be the place to look. My image data is also created from `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`